# IP CAMERA OFF INTERNET

Tags: ip, lan, camera

I recently installed an IP camera on my sytem (Xp Pro Sp3 with cabel modem, linksys router (WRT54G) and 8 port ethernet switch). Problem is the camera eats up a ton of bandwidth. I would like to be able to view the video output only on my LAN system, not on the internet or through the internet, and also be able to save the output to my NAS drive.

I have tried everything I can think of to get it to work to no avail. Foscam the camera manufacturer has not been able to provide a solution. Anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Thanks,
PD

Comment: You might be able to use [YawCam](http://www.yawcam.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to see the camera's output via the Internet, then do not look at it via the Internet. That simple.

If you want to see it via the LAN, connect to it from a computer on the LAN, enter the username and password and watch what the camera sees.  That should **not** use any of your cable modems bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least a couple of ways you can restrict your camera to only working over your LAN.  The easiest would be to remove the "Gateway" IP address from the camera, which means that only systems which are on the same subnet (loosely speaking start with the same IP addresses) will be able to reach the camera.  Provided the PC's used for viewing and NAS are all on your local network this should work fine.

The "Correct" way of doing it, if your hardware supports it is to firewall off access to your camera at your router.